# Where should the enzyme setup file be written?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Yesterday I upgraded my React project to v16.0, but I found that Enzyme had some problems

```
    Error: 
      Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none. To
      configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })`
      before using any of Enzyme's top level APIs, where `Adapter` is the adapter
      corresponding to the library currently being tested. For example:
      import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
      To find out more about this, see http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html

    at validateAdapter (spec/components/page_components/SongListItem/index.spec.js:9:1141986)
    at getAdapter (spec/components/page_components/SongListItem/index.spec.js:9:323041)
    at new ReactWrapper (spec/components/page_components/SongListItem/index.spec.js:9:622193)
    at mount (spec/components/page_components/SongListItem/index.spec.js:9:2025476)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (spec/components/page_components/SongListItem/index.spec.js:9:1235741)
```

And I found a solution on the official [website](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/react-16.html)

```
// setup file
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

But I have a problem: Where should the enzyme setup file be written? In front of each test file?

I tried to add the above code to one of the test files, But there is still a problem

```
 Internal error: attempt to prepend statements in disallowed (non-array) context at C:/Users/killer/workspace/react/NetEase-Cloud-Music-Web/spec/components/page_components/SongListItem/index.spec.js
```

[This](https://github.com/shianqi/NetEase-Cloud-Music-Web) is the address of my project

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had a similar issue

If you are using jest to run your tests, you can create a `test-setup.js` file and add the snippet from the enzyme docs:

```
// test-setup.js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

then add a `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` key in your jest configuration and point to that file. For example, if your jest configuration is in `package.json`:

```
// package.json
{
    ...,
    "jest": {
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"
    }
}
```

from the jest docs
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string:

> The path to a module that runs some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test. Since setupFiles executes before the test framework is installed in the environment, this script file presents you the opportunity of running some code immediately after the test framework has been installed in the environment.

This will execute after your jest environment is initialised, but before your enzyme tests are executed

**For people using create-react-app**
You need to run `yarn eject` or `npm run eject`, then you will see jest configuration in your `package.json`.
In addition, `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` is currently deprecated in favor of `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

Comment: I Tried this and still got the same adapter error, already 3 hour in this issue. Somebody has some other approach?

Comment: No need to eject for modern create-react-app versions. It will execute `src/setupTests` by default. If it does not, you can still pass it as a CLI argument to the `test script` of your `package.json`

`react-scripts test --setupFilesAfterEnv='./src/setupTests.ts'`

Comment: Seconding MrKey's comment-- see @VinceOPS [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627353/where-should-the-enzyme-setup-file-be-written#answer-46810504) for more info.

Answer (score 23):

For people using **create-react-app**, the expected path for your setup file is `src/setupTests.js`. See the [documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#initializing-test-environment) (README) on GitHub:

> Initializing Test Environment
>
> Note: this feature is available with react-scripts@0.4.0 and higher.
>   If your app uses a browser API that you need to mock in your tests or
>   if you just need a global setup before running your tests, add a
>   src/setupTests.js to your project. It will be automatically executed
>   before running your tests.

(As create-react-app does not handle, at least in v1.4.1, the option `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` in package.json).

Answer (score 7):

Update **jun 2019**

Whoever using **CRA**(create-react-app), `src/setupTests.js` won't work! Create `jest.config.js` file in project root folder and paste the content below,

```
module.exports = {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(scss|sass|css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"]
}
```

ModuleNameMapper will avoid static files import statements (optional).

Since `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` has been deprecated, so we have to use `setupFilesAfterEnv` property value as array.

Ensure you have `setupTests.js` file located in your project src folder or specify your setupTests.js file location in your project.

**More Info**

`setupTests.js` file should have below content,

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

This setup works for react 16

Comment: Any commands to be run post this setup?? I get the same error even after the setup that you have asked to do.

Comment: Good one ;) No other command to be ran for me other than `npm run test`

Comment: Might help to install latest react versions following https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/

Comment: And make check I do not keep a unsupported key in "jest" entry from your package.json

Comment: And finally my .eslintrc refers to jest as well to avoid issues with unrecognised "it":
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },

Answer (score 4):

No need to ad a configuration to package.json. Just ad a "setupTests.js" file under "src" folder and add the lines

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

if you try to add configuration jest will be throwing an error like this.

> We detected setupFilesAfterEnv in your package.json.
>
> Remove it from Jest configuration, and put the initialization code in
> src/setupTests.js. This file will be loaded automatically

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with **React v16** throwing **Enzyme internal error**. You have to put the following code in **src/setupTests.js**:

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import EnzymeAdapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

Enzyme.configure({
  adapter: new EnzymeAdapter(),
});
```

Configure **jest** in **package.json** file. Add the following line:

```
  "jest": {
    ...
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

For those, who repeatedly facing issues with React 16 (Functional) and `Jest` with `Enzyme` libraries.

So, `package.json` is for `react-scripts test` is:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --setupFilesAfterEnv='<rootDir>/setupTests.js'",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "jest": "^24.7.1"
  }
}
```

`src/setupTests.js` mentions are:

```
import { configure } from "enzyme"
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

though `Home/index.jsx` component and `Home/index.test.js` are available in same directory, thus:

```
import React from "react"
import Home from "./index"
import { shallow } from "enzyme"

describe("Shallow Home Page", () => {
  it("Home Component Check", () => {
    let home_wrapper = shallow(<Home />)
    console.log("home_wrapper is", home_wrapper.debug())
    expect(home_wrapper.exists(".text-center")).toEqual(true)
  })
})
```

So, what you are waiting for, let's do -

`npm run test`

Hope this would help manyone.